# ReturnUrl is always null on POST using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm not able to get `ReturnUrl` to work on `HttpPost` using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

When adding a breakpoint to the `POST` method, `returnurl` is always null. But with .NET 5, it works with the same code setup except that with .NET 6, I need to make the `returnurl` parameter nullable so that I won't get an error "returnurl field is required".

This is the code I'm using - any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Model:

```
namespace IdentityManagerDotNet6.Models
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string? returnurl)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, string? returnurl)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl;
    returnurl = returnurl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password, loginViewModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnurl);
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }
    }

    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```

View:

```
@model LoginViewModel

<h1 class="text-info">Log in</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" role="form">
            <h4>Use a local account to log in</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check mt-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked">
                <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="RememberMe" for="flexCheckChecked">
                    Remember me?
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class=" col-1 my-3">
                    <button type="submit" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" class="btn btn-success form-control">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <a asp-action="Register">Register as a new user?</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a asp-action="ForgotPassword">Forgot your passord?</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: return url is a query string parameter can you show us the whole url and query string?

Comment: https://localhost:44329/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FPrivacy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`"I'm not able to get ReturnUrl to work on HttpPost using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.":`**

> I have checked your code between the line. It doesn't has anything
> wrong with `[FromQuery]` So you don't need to do anything on `[FromQuery]` as other answer I've seen, may be deleted now.

**`Issue Replication:`**

I have reproduced your issue successfully as you can see below:

[image]

**`What Causing the Issue:`**

> If you investigate your code again you would noticed that you are
> using `asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Login"` twice on your
> `Login.cshtml` at the begining of the `form`  and at the point of `submit button` this causing the data loss while you are submitting the form.

**`At the starting on form:`**

```
   <form asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" role="form">
```

**`At your button submit::`**

```
 <button type="submit" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Login" class="btn btn-success form-control">Login</button>
```

**`Solution:`**

The easiest solution is just modify your `submit button code` like below which will resolve your issue:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class=" col-1 my-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Hope it will resolve your `returnurl` null issue completely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Removing the tag helpsers form button solved the issue

Comment: Glad to assist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string? returnurl) <--  you don't need it
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl; <-- you don't need it
    return View();
}
```

View

```
<form method="post" role="form"> <-- you can do that and the returnUrl 
will be posted to you anyway
```

Or

```
<form method="post" role="form" new { returnUrl = Context.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]} > 
it will work either way
```